# Wifi connection with beacon

Tags: wifi, beacon

I would like to know if it is possible to connect device to a wifi thanks to the beacon. 
I know that I can broadcast an URL but I am not sure that the URL is able to connect wifi. 
We have an app on android and iOs.

Thank you,

Arthur

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to build a third party app on and Android phone that detects a beacon with a specific URL, and then programmatically search for and connect to a particular WiFi access point.  Again, however, this would require a third party app built to do exactly this.  I am unaware of any existing apps that do this.

On iOS, the above is impossible, as iOS does not allow third party apps to initiate WiFi scans and connect to WiFi.